# PUT axios result in 403 with spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, vue.js, axios

This is my code axios:

```
 import axios from 'axios'
import vue from 'vue'

const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'http://localhost:8080',
    json:false
})

export default{
    async execute (method, resource, data){
        return client({
            method,
            url: resource,
            data,            
        }).then(req => {
            return req.data
        })
    },

    startMailService(){
        return this.execute('put', '/task/start')
    },
    stopMailService(){
        return this.execute('put', '/task/stop')
    },
    versao(){
        return this.execute('get', '/email/versao')
    }
}
```

Cors Configuration in spring boot:

```
@Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {                
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }
```

these is are endpoints in spring boot

```
@PutMapping("/start")
    public ResponseEntity<Void> start(){
        taskService.setEnabled(true);

        return ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
    }

@GetMapping("/versao")
    public ResponseEntity<String> versao(){
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body("2.0.0.9");
    }
```

The versao endpoint works perfectly, but start endpoint return in axios http 403 error:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:8080/task/start 403 ()
```

Observation: My api-rest not using spring-security, all endpoints are released.
In the postman not launch any errors.

Whats wrong here ?

Comment: I discovery the problem. The Cors was blocking request of type OPTIONS, i have create filter in using servlet for resolve, because the configuration spring boot not works. If someome have one configuration spring boot realy eficent for CORS, please post here.